# fast syncing has completed, yet eth.blockNumber still returns 0

Tags: go-ethereum, fast-sync

I've ran a fast sync via

> geth --syncmode "fast" --cache 1024

After running for about 12 hours (didn't think fast sync should take that long!) "eth.syncing" finally returns

> false

which I'm led to believe means that the syncing has completed successfully.

Correct?

Yet, when I issue a "eth.blockNumber" it continues to return "0"

Why is this? 
How can I truly know when syncing has completed successfully?

I'm running geth 1.8.0 on Windows 10, and I'm fast losing confidence that running a local node is achievable

HELP!

Comment: what output do you get (if any) when you enter the command "web3.eth.getBlockNumber(console.log)" ?     Also, this is all assuming you are attached to your geth instance with the necessary rpc apis available.

Comment: here's what i get when I run web3.eth.getBlockNumber(console.log)
null 0
undefined